# Exporting ASCII file from 'stars' package

Tags: r, stars

I'm playing around with the `stars` package (0.4-1) in R, but I can't get how to export a grid object in ASCII format, as the traditional `writeRaster(r, filename=file.path(dir.list[j], 'test.asc'), format="ascii")` would do.

On one side I tried

```
write_stars(r, dsn=file.path(dir.list[j], 'test.asc'))
```

but I get

```
Error in CPL_write_gdal(mat, file, driver, options, type, dims, from,  : 
  driver not recognized.
```

On the other hand, if I try to convert it to a `RasterLayer` using the provided function I get different errors:

```
r = as(r)
Error in .identC(thisClass, Class) : 
  "Class"  is not specified and doesn't have a default value


r = stars::as(r)
Error: 'as' is not an object from 'namespace:stars'
```

The [help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/stars/man/coerce-methods.html) is not that helpful and I don't find any other info in the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can your GDAL write ArcInfo ascii grids?

```
> rds = st_drivers(what="raster")
> rds["AAIGrid",]
           name           long_name write copy is_raster is_vector  vsi
AAIGrid AAIGrid Arc/Info ASCII Grid FALSE TRUE      TRUE     FALSE TRUE
```

that shows mine can't write them. The `raster` package gets round this by implementing its own ASCII Grid writing code, and giving it a non-GDAL name of "ascii".

`stars` seems to try and replicate this - its undocumented `detect.driver` function returns "ascii" and then passes this to GDAL which will fail to recognise it:

```
> stars:::detect.driver("foo.asc")
[1] "ascii"
```

So this fails because there's no "ascii" driver:

```
> write_stars(x1, dsn="/tmp/foo1.asc", band=1)
Error in CPL_write_gdal(mat, file, driver, options, type, dims, from,  : 
  driver not recognized.
```

and this fails because I don't have write capability for `AAIGrid`:

```
> write_stars(x1, dsn="/tmp/foo1.asc", band=1, driver="AAIGrid")
Error in CPL_write_gdal(mat, file, driver, options, type, dims, from,  : 
  driver does not support Create() method.
```

If you *do* have write capability for that driver then the above *should* work.

So let's convert to `Raster`...

`r = as(r)` isn't telling `as` what Class you wanted it converted to:

```
> r = as(x1)
Error in .identC(thisClass, Class) : 
  argument "Class" is missing, with no default
```

so tell it...

```
> r = as(x1, "Raster")
> r
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 352, 349, 122848, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
```

Then you can write (one layer of) that to an ASCII Grid using `writeRaster`.

Comment: ha! now I understand why, thank you very much.
BTW, no writing capability here too, so I had to convert back to 'Raster'; I got misled by the help page which looks like asking only for the from parameter.

Comment: This is very usefull as I did not find the way to compress the rasters when using stars::st_rasterize. Now I use r <- as(x, "Raster") and later raster::writeRaster(r,file,options = c("COMPRESS=DEFLATE"))